# Bad encoding PDF using PDF2IMAGE python

Tags: python, pdf, encoding, pdf2image

I'm trying to convert PDF to PNG using pdf2image. Normally it's working good, but for one PDF the text is completely different. It seems to be the encoding but I cannot find any way to solve it. pdf2image can handle this case ? Is it possible to correct the PDF encoding before use pdf2image ?
Thanks for help.

[image: original pdf]

[image: converted pdf]

Comment: Please share the PDF in question for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I cannot share the whole PDF because it's confidential data.. But I have the error after installed ImageMagick (but doesn't use), and I don't have the error when I remove it. Maybe it installed some libraries about PDF decoding ?